# How to make my vector class support direct initialization/assignment

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, aggregate-initialization

My question is surely silly but there are so many holes in my understanding of C++11 and template programming that I don't know how to approach this.

I'm rolling my own very simple linear algebra library:

```
typedef short index_t;

template<int M, int N, typename T = double>
class mat {
    // may want some specialized constructors for mat<1,N,T> and mat<M,1,T>
public:
    T& operator()(index_t i, index_t j) {
        return buf[i + j*M];
    }
    T& operator[](index_t k) { // useful for special cases where matrix is vector
        return buf[k];
    }

    // etc...

private:
    std::array<T, M*N> buf;
}

typedef mat<2, 1, double> col2d;
typedef mat<3, 1, double> col3d;
typedef mat<1, 2, double> row2d;
typedef mat<1, 3, double> row3d;
typedef mat<2, 2, double> mat2d;
typedef mat<3, 3, double> mat3d;
```

I just want it to support a way to assign (or at least initialize) vectors (i.e. matrices with a singleton dimension) directly. For examples, I would like to be able to either do `v = col2d(v1,v2)` or at least `col2d v = {v1,v2}`. I have the impression that making `buf` public might allow `col2d v = {{v1, v2}}` but I don't like the idea of exposing `buf`. I'm not keen on writing out a specialized constructor for each (1,N) and each (M,1). I'm trying to keep the library as simple and readable as possible.

Any advice?

Comment: What about `mat2d x = {{ 1,2,3,4 }};`?  I find such initialization useful in practice.  Should `col2d` and `row2d` be initialized the same way?  How about `mat2d x = { as_flat, {1,2,3,4} };?

Comment: Or `mat3d x = {diagonal, 1,2,3};`?  Does it have to come from an array or separate `{}` or is taking `N*M` values to be converted sound good?   On a scale of 1 to 10 how insanely do you like metaprogramming?  Is runtime bounds/size checking good enough?  Are you sure you do not want to expose `buf`?  Is C++17 ok?

Comment: Initializing matrices is nice but I'd rather do `M(i,j)=mij` than learn metaprogramming. Rows and cols can be initialized same way, except name of constructor in event of using constructor, of course. Taking `N*M` values sounds good. 3/10. Exposing `buf` not out of question - just reluctant. No C++17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mat(std::array<T, M*N>&& buffin):buf(std::move(buffin)){}
mat(std::array<T, M*N> const& buffin):buf(buffin){}
```

This does not expose `buf`, but gives you the `col3d x = {{{ 1,2,3 }}};` syntax.

It also lets a mat 3d be initialized with a flat buffer.  I find this quite useful myself.

I might be tempted to add

```
struct flat_t{constexpr flat_t(){};};
constexpr flat_t flat{};
```

Then prepend the `array` ctors to `mat` with a `flat_t`.  This prevents accidental implicit conversion, while still alowing `return {flat, {{1,2,3}}};` style return.

An alternativd is

```
template<class...Ts,
  std::enavle_if_t< (sizeof...(Ts)==N*M), int> =0
>
mat(flat_t, Ts&&...ts):
  buf{{std::forward<Ts>(ts)....}}
{}
```

Which gives you

```
col2d{flat, 1,2};
```

as a valid `col2d`.

Adding a sfinae test that all of the `Ts` can be converted to `T` is a next step for this path.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me what you think about the answer I just posted? I am interested in any critique that comes to your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
template<int M, int N, typename T = double>
class mat {
public:
    // constructor
    template <typename... Args>
    mat(Args... args) : buf({ args... }) {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == M*N || sizeof...(Args)==0, "Wrong number of arguments in constructor.");
    }
    // etc...
}

// the following aliases replace all those typedefs in the question
template<index_t N, typename T=double>
using row = mat<1, N, T>;
template<index_t M, typename T=double>
using col = mat<M, 1, T>;

template <typename T=double, typename... Args>
col<sizeof...(Args), T> c(Args... args) {
    return col<sizeof...(Args), T>({ args... });
}
template <typename T=double, typename... Args>
row<sizeof...(Args), T> r(Args... args) {
    return row<sizeof...(Args), T>({ args... });
}
```

which allows things like

```
c(1.0, 2.0, 3.0); // returns a col<3>, which is a mat<3,1>
r(1.0, 2.0);      // returns a row<2>, which is a mat<1,2>
r<float>(1.0f, 2.0f); // returns a row<2, float>
```

If there is a simple way for the template function in the last line above to infer the type parameter from the function's arguments' type I would love to know about it.

---

EDIT: (New version incorporating @Yakk's suggestions.)

```
typedef short index_t;

template<int M, int N, typename T = double>
class mat {
public:
    mat() {
    }
    template <typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Args)==M*N), int> = 0> // static assertion doesn't work for external detection of validity, which is needed I think to avoid signature conflict with default, copy, move constructors etc.
    mat(Args&&... args) : buf({ std::forward<Args>(args)... }) {
        //static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == M*N || sizeof...(Args) == 0, "Wrong number of arguments in constructor.");
    }
public:
    T& operator()(index_t i, index_t j) {
        return buf[i + j*M];
    }
    T& operator[](index_t k) {
        return buf[k];
    }

    // etc... various matrix operations

private:
    std::array<T, M*N> buf;
};

// etc... various matrix operators

// aliases for row and col
template<index_t N, typename T=double>
using row = mat<1, N, T>;
template<index_t M, typename T=double>
using col = mat<M, 1, T>;

// short-hand "literals"
template <typename... Args>
col<sizeof...(Args), typename std::common_type<Args...>::type> c(Args&&... args) {
    return col<sizeof...(Args), typename std::common_type<Args...>::type>({ std::forward<Args>(args)... });
}
template <typename... Args>
row<sizeof...(Args), typename std::common_type<Args...>::type> r(Args&&... args) {
    return row<sizeof...(Args), typename std::common_type<Args...>::type>({ std::forward<Args>(args)... });
}
```

Comment: You should use forwarding references and std forward on `Args...`.    A static assert generates a better error message, but prevents external detection of validity of construtor, compared to a SFINAE test.  You can modify `c` and `r` to take `(T arg0, Args... args)`, deducing `T` from the first argument if not passed explicitly.  You could also use `std::common_type` to deduce the type `T` from `Args...`, adding a `typename Explicit=void` that overrides that decision if passed as the first template argument to `c` or `r`.

Comment: @Yakk Thank you for the very useful advice! When it comes to some of this c++11 magic I understand very little but I do understand the gist of what it accomplishes, and somehow managed to incorporate your suggestions. I didn't know how to incorporate your last suggestion though, and would like to. I know this isn't a code review forum, but would you mind eyeballing my new code (appended to this answer) and telling me about any easy and simple improvements that come to your mind?

Comment: `template<class T0, class T1, class...Args> struct get_type{using type=T0;}; template<class T1, class...Args> struct get_type<void, T1, Args...>{using type=T1;}; template<class T0, class T1, class...Ts>using get_type_t=typename get_type<T0,T1,Ts...>::type;` will get `T0` unless it is void, in which case it gets `T1`.  Extending this to instead get `std::common_type<T1, Ts...>::type` is left as an exercise.

Comment: @Yakk That's too deep into the Turing tarpit for me. I'm really happy with where you got me already. Thanks again.